# Why Azure blob container does not show in all resources?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to list all resources from Azure for a give subscription.

But Azure storage blob containers are not shown in the result list.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

> But Azure storage blob containers are not shown in the result list.
>
> Is there a reason for this?

Storage blob containers are child resources for a storage account. You will need to connect to a storage account to view it's child resources (like blob containers, tables etc.)

Comment: Does the resource manager list only show top-level resources?

Comment: You can say that.